# CodeIgniter + NuSOAP - Input multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, xml, web-services, soap, nusoap

I was looking for it several times but didn't find any answer that help me, so I'm asking now and I hope someone can help me.

I have some webservices in a CodeIgniter application that returns complex types and whatever, and now I need create a service that RECEIVE a complex type like this:

```
Array ("position1" => 'mambo jambo',
       "position2" => 'more mambo jambo',
       "position3" => Array("0" => Array(), "1" => Array()),
       "position4" => Array("0" => Array(), "1" => Array());
```

In resume, it a complex type that have some normal data and inside it two arrays that receive N positions of another array. I need it because I receive some Invoice and in invoice I receive N products (every with about 4 positions) and N quotas of payment (every with value, date, etc).

I tryed create a complex type with two positions where every of them as an other complex type that is an array of another complex type. Yes, I know, it is complex =P

Is like this that I use when I create output services to return data like this, but to input doesn't works. When I try test it in SoapUI App that generate this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:SOAPServerWSDL">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:gravaNotaFiscal soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <token xsi:type="xsd:string">?</token>
         <nota_fiscal xsi:type="ped:NotaFiscal" xmlns:ped="http://ultraman/tr1/sistema/api/pedidoservice?wsdl">
            <!--You may enter the following 7 items in any order-->
            <filial xsi:type="xsd:string">?</filial>
            <numero xsi:type="xsd:string">?</numero>
            <serie xsi:type="xsd:string">?</serie>
            <dt_emissao xsi:type="xsd:string">?</dt_emissao>
            <valor xsi:type="xsd:string">?</valor>
           <itens_nota xsi:type="ped:Itens_Nota"/>
           <duplicatas_nota xsi:type="ped:Duplicatas_Nota"/>
         </nota_fiscal>
      </urn:gravaNotaFiscal>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Last two positions "itens_nota" and "duplicatas_nota" need to be my two arrays, but SoapUI doesn't create it right.

Using "itens_nota" for example, I created two complex types like this:

```
$this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType(
                                            'ItemNF',
                                            'complexType',
                                            'struct',
                                            'all',
                                            '',
                                            array(
                                                "filial" => array('name' => 'filial', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                                "serie" => array('name' => 'serie', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
                                                "nota_fiscal" => array('name' => 'nota_fiscal', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                                "seq" => array('name' => 'seq', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                                "pedido" => array('name' => 'pedido', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
                                                "item" => array('name' => 'item', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                                "qtd" => array('name' => 'qtd', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
                                            )
```

);

```
$this->nusoap_server->wsdl->addComplexType("Itens_Nota", 
"complexType", 
"array", 
"", 
"SOAP-ENC:Array", 
 array(), 
                                                  array(array("ref"=>"SOAP-ENC:arrayType","wsdl:arrayType"=>"tns:ArrayOfString[]")),
                          "tns:ItemNF"
 );
```

My input parameter is "Nota_Fiscal", is a complex type and it last two positions is:

```
"itens_nota" => array("name" => 'itens_nota', 'type' => 'tns:Itens_Nota'),
"duplicatas_nota" => array("name" => 'duplicatas_nota', 'type' =>'tns:Duplicatas_Nota')
```

My arrays!

But doesn't works! Someone know why? Where I made mistakes?

If possible I wanna an example of how make a service to input arrays like this, doesn't need be my problem, only an example to give me a direction.

Thanks!